# Why does Maven include change the structure of my required files

Tags: maven, jar, include, file-structure

I want to include the directory "dirA" into my .jar

The structure is the following

```
-mvnModule
     -dirA
        -dirB
           someFiles
        -dirC
           someFiles
     -src
     .......
```

When I do this:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>dirA/*</directory>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

Why is it that if I investigate the .jar-File, all Files are just under the root (mvnModule). Maven removes my structure, which leads to FileNotFoundExcpetions at runtime. I do not want to change all the paths in the code...is there a way to include it with the correct/original structure?

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: First please make a full example project and furthermore why do need such directory structure in a JAR file?

Comment: I need to have the same path's to the file that I am referencing to inside the code. Which works if I run it inside the IDEA because the path is 
dirA/subDir/filename.yaml

I am referencing this path in other classes...If I do a mvn package --> all files are just lying under the project root.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, 
I expect Maven to keep the structure of the directory I include...I say <include> directoryA </indlude> this directory has 2 subdirectories...
All the files are in the build, but not inside any directory...not even directoryA...do you know what I mean...After mvn package the file structure is gone...which I am referencing to inside the code...And I don't want to change the code...I think it can be solved by maven

Comment: Use `dirA` instead of `dirA/*`